# ReactJS state is not updating inside websocket callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the array of react state object in websocket callback function but it's not updating the state neither it's getting updated value from the component.

I already tried answer from other posts but didn't get it working.

How would I fix it?

Code:

```js
const {socket} = useSocket()
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const SendMessage = () => {
        if (message !== "" && phone !== "") {
            HttpClient.post("/web/client/sms/send", {message: message, sanitize: sanitize, phone: phone, sender_id: senderID, check_spam: true}).then(response => {
                if (response.data.code !== 200) {

                } else {
                    setMessages(cur => [...cur, {
                        id: response.data.data.id,
                        from: response.data.data.from,
                        to: response.data.data.to,
                        message: response.data.data.message,
                        service_provider_id: response.data.data.service_provider_id,
                        message_status: response.data.data.message_status,
                    }])
                }
            })
        }
    }

    const updateMessage = (config) => {
        console.log(messages, config)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (socket) {
            socket.on("message:report", updateMessage)
        }
        return () => {
            if (socket) {
                socket.off("message:report")
            }
        }
    }, [socket])
```

In above code `SendMessage` is first called which updates the `messages` state using `setMessages` but the updated value of `messages` is not visible in `updateMessage`

Comment: Try using this signature for setting state `setMessages(currentMessages => {  return updated_value_after_some_modification } )`  - `currentMessages` here, which gives the most recent state of messages.  You could perform some checking internally if that helps.